# Gravity Forms validation without default submit button

Tags: wordpress, forms, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using Gravity Forms & Quotation plugin to create a Quote Form on my Wordpress website. Following is the code for default submit button which checks for validation errors & submits form data to the server.

```
<button class="button alt gform_button" type="submit" id="gform_submit_button_1">Submit</button>
```

Now the problem that I am facing is Gravity Forms validator doesn't fire when default submit button is replaced with following:

```
<button class="button alt" type="button" data-is_quote="1" data-button="simple_add_to_quote" data-product-type="simple" data-product-id="75448" id="add_to_quote">Submit</button>
```

If I change the button code to default then validation works fine. But I can't change the control on the page and have to use the quote button. Any solution?

Comment: What's the reason to change the code? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Quote Form will not work without changing the button code.